# What is this attack? id=1'[0]

Tags: web-application, sql-injection

I'm frequently getting these weird URLs.

```
https://mywebsite.com/mymage.php?id=1'[0]
```

The weird part is `'[0]`.

The webpage pass the id to the database and the database expect an integer so we are frequently getting errors.

Is it an attack? If yes, what is it targeting?

Note: It's similar to this question that doesn't have any answer. [What type of attack is this? '[0]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/232717/what-type-of-attack-is-this-0)

Comment: Well from my point of view looks that somebody is trying to do something like an injection but he dont know what he is doing, another theory could be an automatic bot or tool with a bug on the URL, could be possible for you dump the full request?

Comment: What triggers me in your question is "The webpage pass the id to the database and the database expect an integer so we are frequently getting errors." Does that mean that you do not sanitize your input before passing it to the database? Ever heard of Bobby Tables?

Comment: @LjmDullaart Yes, we sanitize every inputs with Parameterized Queries. https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/SQL_Injection_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html#defense-option-1-prepared-statements-with-parameterized-queries

Comment: Um, you're expecting an integer and you're frequently getting errors?  That implies that you are vulnerable to SQL injection and you need to lock it down *quick* and evaluate the possibility that you may have had all your data stolen...

Comment: @Gudradain So it is your web application that generates these errors, not the database.

Comment: No, it's the database that generates the error. For example, let's say the query is "WHERE id = @id" then the @id parameter get passed to the database. But, the type of the parameter is determined at run time, so it might be passed as a string (varchar) parameter. When the database try to compare an integer with a string (varchar), it will try to convert the string to an integer. If it can't convert the string to an integer then it crashes.

Comment: If your database generates the error depending on what your untrusted input produces, then you are not sufficiently sanitizing your input. It is as simple as that.

Comment: @LjmDullaart The following SQL code will generate an error. `DECLARE @test varchar(10) = 'abc'; SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = @test;` Still, there is no danger of SQL injection here no matter what you put inside the variable `@test`. Before you get confused, the part `DECLARE @test varchar(10) = 'abc';` never appear in our queries. Only this would appear `SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = @test` and we would use a parametrized queries to pass the value of `@test`.

Answer (score 1):

It's a way of an attack, called **"Blind SQL Injection"**. Official Documentation from OWASP: https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Blind_SQL_Injection

> Blind SQL (Structured Query Language) injection is a type of SQL
> Injection attack that asks the database true or false questions and
> determines the answer based on the applications response. This attack
> is often used when the web application is configured to show generic
> error messages, but has not mitigated the code that is vulnerable to
> SQL injection.

[image]

Comment: It's definitely an attempt at SQL injection, but what about this payload makes you think it is specifically blind SQL injection?

Comment: The ' character is usually used to close a string in SQL injection, then you can inject your payload. The weird part is [0] that follows it. In SQL Server, square brackets are used to enclose object name like table or columns.

Comment: This is not a blind sql injection payload.

Answer (score 1):

This attack could help by grabbing the first item from a list and return it, based on how it is being handled. This scanner could be targeting a certain implementation that returns a list, and most of the examples with SQLi state that the first item is an `admin` user, `sa` for example.

- `some_var='` -> breaks the parser early on, no condition is gonna be applied, grab all objects.
- `[0]` -> give me the first entry in that list you got, even if there are duplicates (if a condition is being applied).
- *the scanner could now be checking for `admin` in that response, and if yes, proceeds with the attack.*

**This is purely analytical. I have never seen a similar exploit or attack as this is appears to be targeted.**

If you want to properly protect yourself from this, **review** specifically what's handling that input, then **threat model** every point it goes through.

Taking the example of SQLi, where this input is **only** going into an SQL parser, the below is a way of thinking:

1. We are receiving this weird input, we handle it by rejecting it from the start because it's not an int.
2. If this bypasses the application layer check in point 1, we are using prepared statements to let the database protect the data.
3. If for any case the database is returning a bigger object than what is expected (3MB instead of 200KB), we block the response from going through.

   - **This requires granular knowledge of your application and your queries or it could break your application.**
4. etc.

I'd advise for a similar approach when an exploit is not known and can't be traced to a specific vulnerability.